# How to escape LDAP dn for lookup?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I have a small script (spring/groovy/ldap) that finds, in Active Directory, the 'management tree' under a person,

i.e. from a 'root person' the script finds the root person's direct reports then uses recursion: for each direct report find their direct reports, etc.

the directReports users attribute specifies a list of DN's in the form:

```
CN=Simpson\, Homer,OU=OU_0731DevOps,OU=OU_0100Monitor Services,OU=OU_0001U*Nuclear Energy Corporation,OU=OU_UNuclearUsers,DC=corp,DC=unucleargrp,DC=com
```

The script does an "ldap lookup" for each direct report by DN, e.g.:

```
obj = ldapTemplate.lookup(pDn, new UserAttributesMapper())
```

**Problem**

The ldap lookup throws an InvalidNameException

[LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: LdapErr: DSID-0C090787

I've tried various combinations of escaping but still get the error.

*What am I missing???*

**More Info**

This url https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles /5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx shows which characters to escape:

> Active Directory requires that the following ten characters be escaped
>   with the backslash "\" escape character if they appear in any of the
>   individual components of a distinguished name:

```
Comma   , 
Backslash character \ 
Pound sign (hash sign)  # 
Plus sign   +
Less than symbol    < 
Greater than symbol > 
Semicolon   ; 
Double quote (quotation mark)   " 
Equal sign  = 
Leading or trailing spaces
```

**Tools**

- Groovy
- Spring Boot
- JVM

thanks!

Comment: Could it be a problem in your config file, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12163350/1202807)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by poking around with LDAPNameBuilder.

**TLDR:**

*ldapTemplate.lookup requires stripping off the "DC..*" portion of the DN.*

If you know a cleaner/more-official solution, please post!

**LDAP Lookup fails with a DN like this:**

This DN has "DC=.." components and fails using spring ldap lookup.

```
CN=Simpson\, Homer,OU=OU_0731DevOps,OU=OU_0100Monitor Services,OU=OU_0001U*Nuclear Energy Corporation,OU=OU_UNuclearUsers,DC=corp,DC=unucleargrp,DC=com
```

**LDAP succeeds with this (no "DC" components):**

This DN has no "DC=" components. Spring LDAP template provides the basedn.
    CN=Simpson\, Homer,OU=OU_0731DevOps,OU=OU_0100Monitor Services,OU=OU_0001U*Nuclear Energy Corporation

**Context Reminder**

This application traverses 'management tree.'  It gets a persons *managees* by the 'directReports' attribute (which lists the full-DN's of each direct report). This application wanted to lookup that user by his/her DN.

**Tweak/Example**

This tweak got the ldap lookup to work:

```
User lookupUserByDn(String pDn) {
    // needed this to get it to work
    String dn=pDn.replace(",${ldapConfig.base}","")
    ldapTemplate.lookup(dn, new UserAttributesMapper())
}
```

for the record, my application.yml ldap portion looked like this:

```
spring:
    ldap:
      urls: ldap://dc.corp.unucleargrp.com:389
      base: DC=corp,DC=unucleargrp,DC=com
      username: username_val
      password : password_val
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/#contextsource-configuration

Removing the *base* attribute, All operations going back and forth will use full DNs.